# Error creating dictionary with API data - string indices must be integers

Tags: json, python-3.x

In Python3 I made a program to read an API (from the Brazilian Chamber of Deputies) and get the data in JSON:

```
import requests
url = 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados'

# first create a dictionary with the names and links of each deputy
deputados = {}
for pagina in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
    parametros = {'formato': 'json', 'itens': 100, 'pagina': pagina}
    resposta = requests.get(url, parametros)
    for deputado in resposta.json()['dados']:
        deputados[deputado['nome']] = deputado['uri']

# then read each link and create a dictionary with the data of each deputy
perfis = {}
for chave, valor in deputados.items():
    print(valor)
    print(chave)
    resposta = requests.get(valor)
    for linha in resposta.json()['dados']:
        perfis[chave] = linha['uri']
        perfis[chave]= linha['nomeCivil']
    for linha2 in resposta.json()['ultimoStatus']:
        perfis[chave] = linha2['nomeEleitoral']
        perfis[chave] = linha2['siglaPartido']
        perfis[chave] = linha2['siglaUf']
        perfis[chave]= linha2['urlFoto']
    for linha3 in resposta.json()['ultimoStatus/gabinete']:
        perfis[chave] = linha3['telefone']
        perfis[chave] = linha3['email']
        perfis[chave] = linha3['sexo']
        perfis[chave] = linha3['dataNascimento']
```

But I had this error message:

```
https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178957
ABEL MESQUITA JR.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-067597090c77> in <module>()
      5     resposta = requests.get(valor)
      6     for linha in resposta.json()['dados']:
----> 7         perfis[chave] = linha['uri']
      8         perfis[chave]= linha['nomeCivil']
      9     for linha2 in resposta.json()['ultimoStatus']:

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Here is an example of the data of a page:

```
resposta = requests.get('https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178957')
print(resposta.json())
{'dados': {'id': 178957, 'uri': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178957', 'nomeCivil': 'ABEL SALVADOR MESQUITA JUNIOR', 'ultimoStatus': {'id': 178957, 'uri': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178957', 'nome': 'ABEL MESQUITA JR.', 'siglaPartido': 'DEM', 'uriPartido': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/partidos/36769', 'siglaUf': 'RR', 'idLegislatura': 55, 'urlFoto': 'http://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/178957.jpg', 'data': '2015-02-01', 'nomeEleitoral': 'ABEL MESQUITA JR.', 'gabinete': {'nome': '248', 'predio': '4', 'sala': '248', 'andar': '2', 'telefone': '3215-5248', 'email': 'dep.abelmesquitajr.@camara.leg.br'}, 'situacao': 'Exercício', 'condicaoEleitoral': 'Titular', 'descricaoStatus': None}, 'cpf': '', 'sexo': 'M', 'urlWebsite': None, 'redeSocial': [], 'dataNascimento': '1962-03-29', 'dataFalecimento': None, 'ufNascimento': 'RR', 'municipioNascimento': 'Boa Vista', 'escolaridade': 'Superior Incompleto'}, 'links': [{'rel': 'self', 'href': 'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/178957'}]}
```

Please, does anyone know why the error occurred while creating the second dictionary and starting to supply it?

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a dictionary (`resposta.json()['dados']`), the default iteration in on the *keys* of the dictionary. So `linha` will be `id` or `uri`, etc. That's why you get `string indices must be integers`. It's hard for me to understand what you're trying to do since it's not in English, but if you just want to extract information from the `json` dictionary, you might want to do this:

```
json_res = reposta.json()
perfis.update(json_res['dados'])
perfis.update(json_res['ultimoStatus'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much
I need to create a dictionary with information about Members, but only a few information. In the first block of the program I get the API links (they are from each MP). And every link has all the information of the deputies
In the second dictionary the key will be the name of the deputy and some values on each page

Answer (score 1):

With the `for` loops, you are accessing each key of your dictionary (which is a string), and tring to index that string with another string: basically, you're calling `"id"["uri"]`.

You can avoid the `for` loop and access your variable directly; something like this should work:

```
perfis = {}
for chave, valor in deputados.items():
    print(valor)
    print(chave)
    resposta = requests.get(valor)
    answer = resposta.json()

    perfis.setdefault(chave, {})['uri'] = answer['dados']['uri']
    perfis.setdefault(chave, {})['nomeCivil'] = answer['dados']['nomeCivil']

    perfis.setdefault(chave, {})['nomeEleitoral'] = answer['dadultimoStatusos']['nomeEleitoral']
    perfis.setdefault(chave, {})['siglaPartido'] = answer['dadultimoStatusos']['siglaPartido']
    perfis.setdefault(chave, {})['siglaUf'] = answer['dadultimoStatusos']['siglaUf']
    perfis.setdefault(chave, {})['urlFoto'] = answer['dadultimoStatusos']['urlFoto']

    perfis.setdefault(chave, {})['telefone'] = answer['ultimoStatus/gabinete']['telefone']
    perfis.setdefault(chave, {})['email'] = answer['ultimoStatus/gabinete']['email']
    perfis.setdefault(chave, {})['sexo'] = answer['ultimoStatus/gabinete']['sexo']
    perfis.setdefault(chave, {})['dataNascimento'] = answer['ultimoStatus/gabinete']['dataNascimento']
```